# Which sparse matrix format is preferable for the construction of block matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I would like to construct a block matrix using one of the corresponding [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) formats. Ultimately, the matrix must be converted to CSC.

I essentially obtain the blocks as (dense) numpy arrays (having `ndim == 2`) or occasionally as sparse identities. For each subset of rows (from top to bottom), I add the corresponding blocks from left to right. Currently I am creating the matrix, then assign the blocks based on slices of indices.

My questions (regarding performance) are the following:

1. Is it advisable to use slicing or should I use `scipy.sparse.bmat` instead?
2. If I do use slicing, which matrix type should I use to insert the blocks (I assign slices of the form `M[a:b,:]` and `M[:,a:b]`)?

Comment: Just guessing, but `COO` feels a natural choice for dealing with blocks.

Comment: Well, to quote a `TypeError`: `'coo_matrix' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: The `coo` style of input is the original, and still standard (if not best in all cases) for constructing a sparse matrix.  For iterative assignment to an existing matrix, `lil` format is best.  `bmat` joins the `coo` attributes of the blocks to form a new `coo` (and then converts to the designated format).  It may be convenient, but won't be faster.   `bsr_matrix` is another option, but I haven't worked with it much.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how efficient the scipy methods are, but using the `coo` format it is relatively straight-forward to build the block matrix by hand. All one needs to do is collect the `row`, `col` and `data` attributes of the blocks, add the block offsets to the coordinates (i.e. `row` and `col`) and then concatenate:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter

submat = namedtuple('submat', 'row_offset col_offset block')

def join_blocks(blocks):
    roff, coff, mat = zip(*blocks)
    row, col, data = zip(*map(attrgetter('row', 'col', 'data'), mat))
    row = [o + r for o, r in zip(roff, row)]
    col = [o + c for o, c in zip(coff, col)]
    row, col, data = map(np.concatenate, (row, col, data))
    return sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col))).tocsr()

example = [*map(submat, range(0, 10, 2), range(8, -2, -2), map(sparse.coo_matrix, np.multiply.outer([6, 2, 1, 3, 4], [[1, 0], [-1, 1]])))]

print('Example:')
for sm in example:
    print(sm)

print('\nCombined')
print(join_blocks(example).A)
```

Prints:

```
Example:
submat(row_offset=0, col_offset=8, block=<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>)
submat(row_offset=2, col_offset=6, block=<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>)
submat(row_offset=4, col_offset=4, block=<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>)
submat(row_offset=6, col_offset=2, block=<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>)
submat(row_offset=8, col_offset=0, block=<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>)

Combined
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -6  6]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 -2  2  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 -3  3  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [-4  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```